# Import variables from a message

Tags: ros, c++, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In my code I would like to get a variable from my message and use this in my main.
Whenever I run this code "x" is said to be 0.00. This should be a different number. In my message I declare my variables as float32.
I feel like I don't use `x = msg.x` the proper way. I know that my message is being send the right way. Because in a different code I was able to `ROS_INFO_STREAM(x)`. This showed that it receives the right x value.
Could someone please look at my code and hopefully see where I make a mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <ur5_inf3480/Coor.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
class MoveRobot {
    public:
        double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double roll;
    double pitch;
    double yaw;
    double a;
    void PublishCoordinatesCallback(const ur5_inf3480::Coor msg);
};

void MoveRobot::PublishCoordinatesCallback(const ur5_inf3480::Coor msg) {
    x = msg.x;
    y = msg.y;
    z = msg.z;
    roll = msg.roll;
    pitch = msg.pitch;
yaw = msg.yaw;
a = msg.a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "coordinates");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(30);
    MoveRobot moverobot;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<ur5_inf3480::Coor>("topic_subscribed", 1, &MoveRobot::PublishCoordinatesCallback, &moverobot);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        ROS_INFO("This is x: %.2f", moverobot.x);
    }
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope I won't ask a question which has been asked already. I tried to search the forum and the internet first but I can't find a solution.
Thank you for your answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279954/import-variables-from-a-message/) by [Lauran](https://answers.ros.org/users/32528/lauran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is you never service the callbacks.
This only happens when you do a `spin` call.

However, you are looping without calling spin.

Thus, instead of:

```
while (ros::ok())
{
    ROS_INFO("This is x: %.2f", moverobot.x);
}
loop_rate.sleep();
ros::spin();
```

You need to have

```
while (ros::ok())
{
    ROS_INFO("This is x: %.2f", moverobot.x);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ros::spinOnce();
}
```

Note: `spin()` is ´looping itself, thus the call to `spinOnce` here.

See also: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lauran](https://answers.ros.org/users/32528/lauran/) on 2018-01-16**:
Thank you for your answer! The change in code didn't show any difference. It still just said x was 0.00. But when I started reading your link I saw that I might need to switch loop_rate.sleep(); and ros::spinOnce(); I did this and now it first says x=0.00 and then after a second it gives the right x

**Comment by [Lauran](https://answers.ros.org/users/32528/lauran/) on 2018-01-16**:
I am on the right track! Whenever I set my ros::Rate loop_rate(); faster. x goes from 0.00 to the value faster. Is there a clean way to publish my message immediately instead just after a second or something like that?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-16**:
Well, this is the Subscriber side. So how fast this changes also depends on how fast the Publisher side is actually publishing.

switching the `sleep` and the `spinOnce` shouldn't make much of a difference *after* the inital message has been received.

**Comment by [Lauran](https://answers.ros.org/users/32528/lauran/) on 2018-01-16**:
Okay, I will just make it publish fast then. Thank you for your help and the link. This forum really makes me learn more :)